# Query String length limit in FETCH

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I'm using Fetch API to make an http GET request which includes a long query string.

It works fine with a query string that 2,176 characters long but doesn't work with the query string that 3,898 characters long

Tried the same request with Postman and browser which both work correctly

```
const response = await fetch(
          `${apiUrl}/auth/decrypt_token?token=${encodeURIComponent(
            token
          )}`
   );
```

I expected the request return 200 code or at least some error code. However only get the fetch: empty response error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no hard limit in terms of what's allowed in a query string, in practice you are going to get problems with urls over about 2000 characters.

There's no reasonable fix for this. You will have to find a different way to transmit the data.